# Ordering of answers on existing questions

Tags: support, answers

Take this question and answer set into consideration : [Why is there something instead of nothing?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/821/why-is-there-something-instead-of-nothing)

The content is irrelevant in this case, my question is why is the highest voted answer not listed first, and the lowest listed last, etc.

Other stacks prioritize answers this way, is there a reason why this stack does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the right above the answers list, you can select by what you want to sort.

There are some exceptions for the 'votes' ordering (e.g. when a user accepts his own answer, and another answer has many more upvotes) but those are not the case here so it seems you have it set to 'active' or 'oldest'.

[image]